# How to solve the interrupt by signal 9: SIGKILL?

Tags: python

Below is my code:

```
 with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    vectors = {}
    for line in f:
        vals = line.rstrip().split(' ')
        vectors[vals[0]] = vals[1:]
```

And it got this: Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL). How should I optimize my code?

Comment: Please provide the stack trace.

Comment: It's this the full code. Use `for line in f.readlines():` Don't forget closing the file after use with `f.close()`

Comment: `SIGKILL` means your python process was likely killed by some external script/tool, e.g. `kill -9 <proc-id>`, not something you can do anything about other than find what sent that signal.

Comment: Still the interrupt. My computer's memory is 8G, and the file is 5G. It would not be caused by running out of memory?

Comment: @RajanChauhan `readlines()` will simply read the whole 5GB file into memory - how will that help? No need for for `close()` when using `with` context manager.

Comment: The file is the pretrained word embedding matrix, glove.42B.300d.txt

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    vectors = {}
    for line in f.readlines():
        vals = line.rstrip().split(' ')
        vectors[vals[0]] = vals[1:]
```

Comment: why should that help?

Comment: `for line in f: ` the content of the `f` is not read into system memory.

Comment: I meant how would that avoid a `SIGKILL`?

Comment: please provide the test file.

Comment: The file is the pretrained word embedding matrix, glove.42B.300d.txt, which size is 5G.